# Use selected svg id as a parameter

Tags: d3.js

My HTML:

```
<svg id="x"></svg>
<svg id="y"></svg>
<svg id="z"></svg>
```

My JS:

```
const svg = d3.selectAll("svg");
console.log(svg.attr("id"));
```

The output in the log:

```
x
```

I was expecting:

```
x
y
z
```

I would like to do something in my script depending on the id of the svg. Like:

```
svg.attr("id") == 'y' ? 0 : 1
```

Is it possible to grab the selected svg element's id and use it as a parameter in the JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a d3 selection and compare it's attributes as shown below.

```js
d3.selectAll("svg").each(function() {
  var svg = d3.select(this);
  var id = svg.attr("id");
  var value = id == 'y' ? 0 : 1;
  console.log(" ID : "+id+", Value: "+value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="x"></svg>
<svg id="y"></svg>
<svg id="z"></svg>
```